# Classcast exception on the server side when making a Post request using Jersey

Tags: dropwizard, embedded-jetty, jersey-client

I am making a call to a Rest service developed using Dropwizard and able to successfully make calls to Get requests however Post request to the same service (another end point offcourse) is not working. It gives a 500 server error and in the logs I see the following exception:

```
Classcast exception: io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler$WrappedInputStream cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.server.request
```

Here is a snippet of how I am making a call:

```
RequestPojo pojo = new RequestPojo (123, "test");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json=null;
try{
  json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
}
catch(Exception e){
   //loggers
}
Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.Application_JSON).post(Entity.json(jsonString);
String id = response.readEntity(new GenericType<Map>(){}.get("generatedID"));
```

I hardly see anything for this exception on any of the posts. Can some one help me with this exception. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you share the snippet where the resource is defined in the Dropwizard service?

Comment: I got this working by setting gzipEnabled and chunkedEncodingEnabled to false but now another Put request is not working. :(

Comment: I could be of more help if you could put up here the code snippet from the resource class.

Comment: Thanks Dhruvil but I got it to work.

Comment: It'd be great if you could update the question to reflect the solution. It'll help others.